# Bitmap to File, Not showing in Default Gallery App

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I have this snippet, which is creating image from view. File can be seen in file manager and accessible through code, but default android gallery app is not showing them.

```
Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);

view.draw(canvas);


ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
returnedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);

Date now = new Date();      
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Download" + File.separator +now.getTime()+".png";

File f = new File(path);
try {
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    fo.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the file to the gallery. Try this code from the developer's website:

```
  private void galleryAddPic(String path) {
      Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
      File f = new File(path);//your file path
      Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
      mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
      this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
  }
```

**Note** make sure that you are not saving in the private memory of the app.

Comment: this worked, below this @Robin answered another solution. I dont know the difference, would you mind differentiating and best method to implement ?

Comment: @user3709251 Technically I havenot used Robin's solution. So I cannot say what is better. My solution is taken from developers website and it uses broadcast receiver. using broadcast receiver enables apps like filemanager (es file explorer) to monitor the changes in the filesystem. So other apps can handle that change. Like google+ app it will upload a photo from the filesystem as soon as there is a new photo. Its up to you to implement and find the best solution according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that to use MediaScanner is better, you can get the URI of the content stored in media database.

```
static final class PicScanner implements MediaScannerConnectionClient {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private static PicScanner mInstance;
        private String mFilename;
        private String mMimetype;
        private MediaScannerConnection mConn;

        public static void scan(Context ctx, File file, String mimetype) {
            mInstance = new PicScanner (ctx, file, mimetype);
        }

        private PicScanner (Context ctx, File file, String mimetype) {
            this.mFilename = file.getAbsolutePath();
            mConn = new MediaScannerConnection(ctx, this);
            mConn.connect();
        }

        @Override
        public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
            mConn.scanFile(mFilename, mMimetype);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            mConn.disconnect();
            mInstance = null;
            //notifyNewPicSavedLocally(path, uri);
        }
    }
```

Usage example:

```
PicScanner.scan(mContext, picFile, "image/jpeg"); //picFile should be access-able for other process
```

Comment: would you mind telling me the difference from the above answer from @Illegal Argument